How to connect to a Docker container from another machine?
I'm running a postgreSQL database in a Docker container on one computer, and I want to connect to this database from another computer. Both computers are on the same network. How can I do this?
I tried connecting using the IP address of the first computer and the database port, but it didn't work.

Did you start the database with a published port (docker run -p ...:5432 or Compose ports: ['...:5432'] option)?  Are there firewall concerns, or other similar things like AWS security groups?  How to communicate with a running Docker container in a Host X from another Host Y(not from a container in Host Y) is old but has an explanation.
